# How to translate multiple fasta sequences?

Tags: bioinformatics, fasta

So I have a FASTA file with multiple sequences that I need to translate (cDNA so I don't need to search for a start codon). I can clean it up a bit and get it to print out  only the sequences but I can't seem to get them to translate to the protein sequence (I don't want to use BioPython). Any advice is much appreciated.

```
#Open the file for reading
FASTA=open('mRNA_database.fasta', 'r')


def readSeq(FASTA):
    for line in FASTA:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            continue
        line = line.strip()
        #print(line)

g_code=dict()
g_code = {'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M',
    'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
    'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
    'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',
    'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L',
    'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
    'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
    'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
    'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V',
    'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
    'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
    'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
    'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S',
    'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
    'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'stop', 'TAG':'stop',
    'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'stop', 'TGG':'W'}

seq = readSeq(FASTA)

def aa_to_prt(seq, g_code):
    prt = ''
    for i in range(0, len(seq), 3):
        codon = seq[i:i+3]
        prt+= g_code[codon]
    return prt
aa_to_prt(seq, g_code)
```

Comment: looks like your readSeq function doesn't return a value. The rest of the code seems to work fine

Comment: As well as not returning a value, it doesn't properly concatenate lines or deal with multiple sequences properly.  You probably want to identify each sequence, concatenate it, translate it, and then move on to the next sequence; all you're doing now (even if you return lines) is translating each line. Also, you aren't looking for start or stop codons, so this may turn out gibberish if you don't have a curated set of nucleotide inputs.  If this is a real problem and not a homework exercise, there is no reason to avoid BioPython, which can deal with these and other issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to translate a FASTA sequence from dict/ how to make function output a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305314/how-to-translate-a-fasta-sequence-from-dict-how-to-make-function-output-a-strin)

Answer (score 0):

Your readSeq function doesn't return any values.  Also, it doesn't properly concatenate lines or deal with multiple sequences correctly. All you're doing now (even if you return lines) is translating each line.

Here's an improved version of your script, but I still do not recommend using this; it is still very naive. For example, this version (like yours) doesn't looking for start or stop codons, so this may turn out gibberish if you don't have a curated set of nucleotide inputs.

If this is a real problem and not a homework exercise, there is no reason to avoid BioPython, which can deal with these and other issues and has been extensively tested against real-world issues.

```
# No need to define g_code as a dict first
g_code = {'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M',
    'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
    'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
    'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',
    'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L',
    'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
    'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
    'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
    'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V',
    'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
    'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
    'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
    'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S',
    'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
    'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'stop', 'TAG':'stop',
    'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'stop', 'TGG':'W'}

def readSeq(fastaF):
    fasta_nts = {}  # We can use a dict to keep the header information 
    fasta_description = '' 
    with open(fastaF, 'r') as f:  # Use the with ... as f syntax to ensure proper file handling
        for line in f.readlines():  # readlines, not read
            if line.startswith('>'): 
                fasta_description = line[1:].strip() # Skip the first character (">") and remove newline
                # Store the sequence, line by line, in a list; much faster and more efficient than building a string
                fasta_nts[fasta_description] = []  
            else:
                fasta_nts[fasta_description].append(line.strip()) # Append each line to the list 
        return fasta_nts  # Remember to return something from the function

def aa_to_prt(seq):   # Not necessary to pass g_code dict each time
    prt = []  # Again, build lists, not strings
    for i in range(0, len(seq), 3):
        codon = seq[i:i+3].upper()  # In case fasta sequence is lowercase - make sure matches your keys
        if len(codon) == 3:  # If it's not a 3-character codon it will throw a KeyError
            prt.append( g_code[codon] ) 
    return ''.join(prt) # Join the list at the end to make a string

fastaF = input_file_path
fasta_nts = readSeq(fastaF) 

fasta_prts = {}  # Final output will save the fasta description as dict key
for (description, sequence_list) in fasta_nts.items():
    fasta_prts[description] = aa_to_prt(''.join(sequence_list))
```